# Move chat footers on all sites to align with chat room boxes

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, chat, design, footer

Please align the footer of the chat websites such that it is aligned with the content of the chat room selection page.

The footer is currently left aligned and looks odd.

> [image: move footer to middle]

This is how it looks like on the main site: (with 1920x1080 screen resolution)

> [image]

Another example from Cooking.SE:

[image: Cooking.SE example]

Comment: Seems site-specific, CR chat has that chunk right-aligned. Which site?

Comment: Guess you mean on Stack Overflow chat only, so this might have better luck posted on Stack Overflow meta. (By posting here, you make it refer to all sites)

Comment: @Catija  see screenshot, the footer in chat does not have the same width as in the site itself and it's indeed bit odd

Comment: @Catija maybe new nav, dunno. Can you post screenshot?

Comment: @Catija you probably have a small screen resolution. I'm using 1920x1080 (which I believe is the standard for most people) and since the contents have fixed width of 1000px or so, they are centered.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Better?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - This is for all chat sites not just SO.

Comment: OK, fair enough. At first I thought it happens only on SO.